# Will key-value pairs of NSUserDefaults persist after minor/major ios update?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I would like to know if you have any experience on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user updates yes

If the user restores no

If the user backs up then restores then restores from backup yes

Comment: defaults will persist also if the bundle name remains the same.